# Cubic equation solver gives wrong answer

Tags: c#

[SOLUTION HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342590/im-failing-to-solve-a-cubic-equation)

I'm trying to write my own cubic equation solver program using C#, but I am getting the wrong answer.
I will thoroughly explain all the steps I have taken, in the hopes of you finding the mistake.

First, I depressed the cubic from the standard form of ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d into x^3 + px + q.
From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc&t=1028s) video by Mathologer, I learned how to do this (he explains it at 16:05).

I implemented it like this:

```c#
double p = (c / a) - (Math.Pow(b, 2) / (3 * Math.Pow(a, 2)));
double q = (2 * Math.Pow(b, 3)) / (27 * Math.Pow(a, 3)) - (b * c) / (3 * Math.Pow(a, 2)) + (d / a);
```

After that, I calculated the discriminant, with the method show in [Mathologer's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc&t=1028s) at 19:00:

```c#
double disc = Math.Pow(q / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(p / 3, 3);
```

With the discriminant calculated, I could move on to the next step, in which I check if the discriminant is positive, zero or negative. Right now I'm having issues with the answer I get from the positive discriminant.

I then calculated the values for u and v (method shown at [23:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc&t=1028s)) and added them together to get the value of x.

For this, I created my own cubeRoot function, which works 100%. (I checked)

```c#
if (disc > 0) {
  double u = cubeRoot(-q / 2 + Math.Sqrt(disc));
  double v = cubeRoot(-q / 2 - Math.Sqrt(disc));
  double x = u + v;
}
```

When I input: a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5. I get the result: x = -0.8711. But when I graphed 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x + 5 in Desmos, I found that x should be -1.3711

I tested all the steps I took, and found that:

p = 1.25

q = 1.75

disc = 0.8379

u = 0.3431

v = -1.2142

I checked everything with my calculator, and it seems like I did everything correctly.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my process?

EDIT:
It seems like my answer is off by exactly 0.5. Why is that?

EDIT 2:
I've moved my question to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342590/im-failing-to-solve-a-cubic-equation), because I feel like the code isn't the problem here, but the math is.

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `c`?  If they are `int` then `c / a` will do integer division that will truncate after the decimal.  And just to be safe you might want to change all the constants to end in `.0` to make sure you're always dealing with doubles and not integers.

Comment: All number I use are of the type double, so that shouldn't be the problem. I realised my answer is off by exactly 0.5, do you know why that is the case?

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to liberally use parenthesis to make sure the correct order of operations.  For instance your second equation is equivalent to `((2 * Math.Pow(b, 3)) / (27 * Math.Pow(a, 3))) - ((b * c) / (3 * Math.Pow(a, 2))) + (d / a)` but you need to check if that's actually correct.

Comment: I already checked everything with my calculator, so I don't think the actual calculations are going wrong here. I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with solving cubic equations. Maybe I'm just missing a step.

Comment: If you think your issue is purely with the math equations you might want to try posting on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that :)

Comment: If anyone's interested, here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342590/im-failing-to-solve-a-cubic-equation